# Multi-select foreign key filter

Tags: symfony1, filter, admin, generator

I'm trying to set up a multi-select filter on a foreign key in the symfony admin.  I think I've set up everything correctly but for some reason it's not working:

```
public function configure()
{
    parent::configure();

    $s = Doctrine_Query::create()->
      from('Status s')->
      execute();

    $status_choices = array();
    foreach ($s as $key => $value) {
        $status_choices[$value->getId()] = $value->getName();
    }

    $this->widgetSchema['status_id'] = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => $status_choices, 'multiple' => true, 'expanded' => true));

    $this->validatorSchema['status_id'] = new sfValidatorChoice(array('required' => false, 'choices' => $status_choices, 'multiple' => true));



}

public function getFields()
{

    $fields = parent::getFields();
    $fields['status_id'] = 'StatusId';
    return $fields;

}

public function addStatusIdQuery(Doctrine_Query $query, $field, $values)
{
    $fieldName = $this->getFieldName($field);

  if (!empty($values))
  {
        $query->addWhereIn(sprintf('%s.%s', $query->getRootAlias(), $fieldName), $values);
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your validatorSchema, to validate data posted, you have to use array_keys($status_choices)
because values sent after posting the form are keys and not labels.

And the addWhereIn is not a Doctrine_Query method, use andWhereIn or whereIn

Hope that will help you